# V+ing Vs. is v+ing?

Tags: difference, verbs, present-tense

What's the difference between those two sentences? Why don't they equal each other?

1. Robert is eating launch.
2. Robert eats launch.

Does one expresses continues action and the other don't?

Comment: Did you mean 'lunch'?

Comment: continuous action: Please check your spelling before posting.

Answer (score 1):

Number 1 indicates Robert is in the process of eating at the moment of speaking. Number 2 indicates that Robert eats lunch; by itself I would take it to mean that Robert eats lunch on a normal day, as opposed to being someone who normally does not.

It's not a matter of "continuing action" as much as a matter of whether the action is happening at the time of speaking.